# toggle clolor change with getElementByClassName not working

Tags: javascript, toggle, togglebutton

html

```
<div class="btn-group float-right text-center">
 <button class="like-button" type="button">
  <div class="material-icons" style="font-size: 18px">thumb_up</div>
   <text class=like-count>12</text>
 </button>
</div>
```

css

```
    .like-button {
  text-align: center;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.333em 0.7em 0.25em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 150ms ease-in-out, background-color 150ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease-in-out;
  outline: 0 !important;

}
.like-button:hover {
  color: indianred;
}
.like-button:active {
  transform: scale(0.95);
}
.like-button {
  text-align: center;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.333em 0.7em 0.25em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 150ms ease-in-out, background-color 150ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease-in-out;
  outline: 0;
}
.like-button.selected {
  color: #dd2a7b;
}
```

javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var likeButton = document.getElementByClassName("like-button");
  likeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.lb = likeButton;
    likeButton.classList.toggle("selected");
  });
}, false);
```

My goal is to toggle the button's color on click like a regular like button.
I was using id tag and found out it only works for first item.
so I changed the code with class tag but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using `document.getElementByClassName` which doesn't exist, you should use `document.getElementsByClassName`.

```
var likeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("like-button");
```

This will return an Array-like object which you can iterate to add the event listeners:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var likeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("like-button");
  for (let i = 0; i < likeButtons.length; i++) {
    var likeButton = likeButtons[i];
    likeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      window.lb = this;
      this.classList.toggle("selected");
    });
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.like-button {
  text-align: center;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.333em 0.7em 0.25em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 150ms ease-in-out, background-color 150ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease-in-out;
  outline: 0 !important;
}

.like-button:hover {
  color: indianred;
}

.like-button:active {
  transform: scale(0.95);
}

.like-button {
  text-align: center;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.333em 0.7em 0.25em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 150ms ease-in-out, background-color 150ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease-in-out;
  outline: 0;
}

.like-button.selected {
  color: #dd2a7b;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group float-right text-center">
  <button class="like-button" type="button">
  <div class="material-icons" style="font-size: 18px">thumb_up</div>
   <text class=like-count>12</text>
 </button>
</div>
```

Since the callback of your event listener references the likeButton and, since you are using `getElementsByClassName` to get multiple likeButtons, you should use `this` to avoid using the last element in the array.

Comment: Thank you it works!  May I ask one more? I got this code from codepen and can't find out  why `window.lb` is used.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have misspelled: var likeButton = document.getElement**s**ByClassName("like-button");
2. `getElementsById` returns collection of elements, not a single element. You should use loop:

```
var likeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("like-button");

for (var i = 0; i < likeButtons.length; i++) {
  likeButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.lb = likeButtons[i];
    this/*this == current div element*/.classList.toggle("selected");
  });
}
```

0. and please provide the error message in your question

Answer (score 0):

Did you test your code? Because **document.getElementByClassName** isn't a standard function implemented by any browser. Did you implemented it by yourself? if then can you show us the code? If not your code will always thrown an exception.

Anyway. 
The standard function (always best choice) implemented in all browser is **document.getElementsByClassName()** wich returns a live HTMLCollection (simplified a js array like structure)
So you should do in this way:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // with destructuring we get the first element of the collection and instanciate the var likeButton
  var [likeButton] = document.getElementsByClassName("like-button");
  likeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.lb = likeButton;
    likeButton.classList.toggle("selected");
  });
}, false);
```

Snippet:

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        // with destructuring we get the first element of the array and instanciate the var likeButton
        var [likeButton] = document.getElementsByClassName("like-button");
        likeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            window.lb = likeButton;
            likeButton.classList.toggle("selected");
        });
    }, false);
```

```css
    .like-button {
        text-align: center;
        color: #888;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        padding: 0.333em 0.7em 0.25em;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: color 150ms ease-in-out, background-color 150ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease-in-out;
        outline: 0 !important;

    }

    .like-button:hover {
        color: indianred;
    }

    .like-button:active {
        transform: scale(0.95);
    }

    .like-button {
        text-align: center;
        color: #888;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        padding: 0.333em 0.7em 0.25em;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: color 150ms ease-in-out, background-color 150ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease-in-out;
        outline: 0;
    }

    .like-button.selected {
        color: #dd2a7b;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn-group float-right text-center">
        <button class="like-button" type="button">
            <div class="material-icons" style="font-size: 18px">thumb_up</div>
            <text class=like-count>12</text>
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyway in my opinion in your case i would use an id for the button and select it with **document.getElementById()**. In this way no destructuring needed to get the element, just add the event listener